# Implicit class for subtypes of a generic class

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to enhance all `Iterable`s with some custom code.
For this I wrote the following:

```
implicit class RichIterable[A, B <: Iterable[A]](b: B) {
  def nonEmptyOpt: Option[B] = if (b.nonEmpty) Some(b) else None
}
```

Now, when I want to use this method on a `List` that definitely is a subclass of `Iterable` like so

```
List(1, 2, 3).nonEmptyOpt
```

I get

```
value nonEmptyOpt is not a member of List[Int]
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a parameter with only type `B <: Iterable[A]`, the compiler doesn't know how to easily figure out what `A` is, because it is not necessarily easily computed from `B` (needing to search for least upper-bounds).

Instead you can do this by redefining the type constraints, without using tricks. Essentially, `B` should really be a *type constructor* that is bounded above by `Iterable`. Then, your implicit class is a conversion from some `B[A]` to your enriched class. Having a parameter of `B[A]` helps the compiler compute `A`, because it expects it to be the argument of the type constructor `B`.

```
implicit class RichIterable[A, B[X] <: Iterable[X]](b: B[A]) {
  def nonEmptyOpt: Option[B[A]] = if (b.nonEmpty) Some(b) else None
}

scala> List(1, 2, 3).nonEmptyOpt
res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> List.empty[Int].nonEmptyOpt
res1: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

Comment: Just curious, is anything lost/changed by going "existential"? `RichIterable[A, B[_] <: Iterable[_]](b: B[A]) {...`

Comment: @jwvh This loses the exacta return type for all subclasses that don't have exactly 1 type parameter, that is the same as in the `Iterable` they extend. Some examples of that are `Map[A, B]` or `scala.xml.NodeSeq`. E.g., `Map(1->2).nonEmptyOpt` will be `Option[Iterable[...]]`, not `Option[Map[...]]`

Comment: @Kolmar, I've been going back and forth between `B[X] ...` and `B[_] ...`, and so far I've been unable to discern any difference in `Map()` handling.

Answer (score 7):

Little trick I stumbled upon once:

```
scala> implicit class RichIterable[A, B <: Iterable[A]](b: B with Iterable[A]) {
 |   def nonEmptyOpt: Option[B] = if (b.nonEmpty) Some(b) else None
 | }
defined class RichIterable

scala> List(1,2,3).nonEmptyOpt
res3: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Note the `B with Iterable[A]` on the parameter.

By the way, when debugging implicits, it helps sometimes to try to apply them explicitly (before change):

```
scala> new RichIterable(List(1,2,3)).nonEmptyOpt
<console>:15: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,List[Int]] do not conform to class RichIterable's type parameter bounds [A,B <: Iterable[A]]
          new RichIterable(List(1,2,3)).nonEmptyOpt
```

So, the compiler is having a hard time figuring out the type of `A`. The type refinement apparently helps it along.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be:

```
implicit class RichIterable[A](b: Iterable[A]) {
  def nonEmptyOpt: Option[Iterable[A]] = if (b.nonEmpty) Some(b) else None
}

scala> List(1,2,3).nonEmptyOpt
res0: Option[Iterable[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is you've converted a List to an Iterable.